# gnuplot change color of the connecting lines

Tags: graph, colors, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot for the following. I have n equations which I want to plot based on the xaxis value. Here is a sample

```
set xrange[0:25]
f1(x) = x
f2(x) = 3*x
f3(x) = 10*x
plot (x>0)&&(x<10)?f1(x):(x<20)?f2(x):f3(x)
```

I know that we can set the color of the line easily by using the below. But it changes the whole color

```
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "blue"
```

But what I want is to make the connecting lines a different color. ie if you plot the above graph you will 5 lines. 3 original lines (from the function) and 2 lines (the almost vertical lines) connecting them. I want to change the color of the connecting lines.

Note 1: These functions are automatically generated by a program, and the number of functions could be large. Even the exact plot command is automatically generated

Note 2: I want a way to differentiate my original lines with the interpolated lines which joins my original lines.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

What you actually have is one line defined piecewise, and there isn't an easy way to define colors for line segments within a piecewise line in gnuplot.

### Easy way (plot a data file)

I would recommend making a data file looking like this:

```
# x y color
0   0   0
10  10  0
10  10  1
10  30  1
10  30  0
20  60  0
20  60  1
20  200 1
20  200 0
25  250 0
```

Notice the double points at x=10 and x=20.  This is so the line segments meet at the transitions.

Now plot it with `linecolor variable`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset

set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color dashed rounded lw 5 size 3,2 font 'Arial,14'
set output 'output2.pdf'

set style data lines
set key top left
set tics scale 0.5 out nomirror

plot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 lc variable
```

It looks like this:

[image]

You can change the palette (`set palette`) to determine the colors, and you can have more than 2 color values in the data file if you want.

### Harder way (only OK for few segments)

You could define 2n-1 separate lines and connect them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset

set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color dashed rounded lw 5 size 3,2 font 'Arial,14'
set output 'output.pdf'

set style data lines
set key top left
set tics scale 0.5 out nomirror

# points every 0.001 units in the range 0:25
set samples 25001

# main lines
f1(x) = (x <= 9.999)                   ? x    : 1/0
f3(x) = (x >= 10.001) && (x <= 19.999) ? 3*x  : 1/0
f5(x) = (x >= 20.001)                  ? 10*x : 1/0

# define slopes and y-offsets of connecting lines
m2 = (f3(10.001)-f1(9.999))/0.002
b2 = (30.0-10.0)/2.0 + 10.0
m4 = (f5(20.001)-f3(19.999))/0.002
b4 = (200.0-60.0)/2.0 + 60.0

# connecting functions
f2(x) = (x >= 9.999) && (x <= 10.001)  ? m2*(x-10) + b2 : 1/0
f4(x) = (x >= 19.999) && (x <= 20.001) ? m4*(x-20) + b4 : 1/0

plot [0:25] f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x), f5(x)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply. The functions are generated by a program. It could have a huge number of functions But constructing data file is not a nice option for me as it could grow too huge. The second one seems much more nice, but since there a huge number of functions, its very hard for me

Comment: How does the program generate functions?  Could it not also generate code for the connecting functions, or a data file for either of these methods (or Bernhard's)?  (I could be wrong, but I am assuming that if code is making functions specifically for gnuplot it is something you can edit to your needs.)

Comment: I can edit the code of generating functions. But since these are interpolated lines, I was looking for a direct way from gnuplot if possible. Even the line style or the ability to turn off these lines would work

Comment: That simplifies things quite a bit if you can ignore the connecting lines... you can then use my second method ignoring f2(x) and f4(x), or see @Christoph's answer.  One thing to note is to use a large sample number (as in my example) if you don't want a horizontal gap between lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a secondary function to define the breakpoints of your function, which is automatically coloring the right linepiece. The below code is easy to extend to different functions and breakpoints (i.e., you can just change `x1` or `x2`). Adding multiple points is also straightforward.

```
xmin=0.
xmax=25.
x0=0.
x1=10.
x2=20.
nsample=200.


dx=(xmax-xmin)/nsample
print dx
set xrange[xmin:xmax]
set sample nsample
f1(x) = x
f2(x) = 3*x
f3(x) = 10*x
f4(x) = (x>x0)&&(x<x1)?f1(x):(x<x2)?f2(x):f3(x)
f5(x) = x
f5(x) = ( (x>x1&&x<=x1+dx) || (x>x2&&x<=x2+dx) )?1:0

set cbrange [0:1]
unset key

plot '+' using 1:(f4($1)):(f5($1)) lc variable with lines
```

Not that I have use the special filename `'+'`, which just constructs a data file with equally space datapoints (following `nsample`).

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. The functions for me are generated by a program. It may output a huge number of functions. So to manually add the rest of functions in your approach would be really hard for me

Comment: Well, then how do you output the function in your initial script in your question? It would not be different. Please ask what you actually need then.

Comment: Those are the actual inputs. To be clear... I have a program P which outputs a set of gnuplot functions (like above). Based on the input to P, the number of gnuplot functions ( f1(x), f2(x) .... fn(x)) vary. All I want is to differentiate the lines generated from these functions with the lines connecting them. I hope it is clear

Comment: You can output the `plot` command (e.g., my `f4(x)`). If it is a huge number of functions, it would be variable, and I suppose you generate the line in your code with `plot`. Then you can also easily generate the function described the vertical lines (it is even simpler). Otherwise, I don't understand you, and you are asking for the wrong things here.

Comment: the plot command is also generated by the program. I hope you read everything clearly. As I said in the above, these added/unwanted lines are interpolated by gnuplot. What I am looking for is a nice way to handle this. I was looking for an inbuilt support if possible to change the color or line style of this interpolated line. All I need is an indication that those were not a part of original function. plot with linesplot shows marks over my line. This is the best solution I found till now. ONCE AGAIN ALL I WANT IS TO DIFFERENCIATE MY ORIGINAL LINES WITH THE INTERPOLATED LINES.

Comment: @knightrider I answered the question you asked, period. Please be careful with people investing time in answering your question, and think about how you phrase it. You can better get rid of these lines, by just plotting `plot (x<10)?x:1/0, (x>10&&x<20)?3*x:1/0, x>20?10*x:1/0`

Comment: @knightrider We understood what you want, no need to shout. But in the meantime you should have also recognized, that there is no builtin functionality for this. And you have three (and a half) answers. Instead of insisting on an answer which follows your imaginary way, you should consider modifications of the existing answers to solve your problem.

Comment: @Christoph As I said I was looking for the straight forward answer. I now understand will the all above explanation that a there is no simple way. I was looking for a simple way that's all if possible if not I will work with these partial solutions

Comment: @Bernhard I think my msg reached u in wrong way. By the caps all I meant was to stress the point that, I just need to differentiate them. May be someone has a genious idea (like changing line style for these lines etc; I am not restricted to change color). It was not meant for anything else. I really appreciate they way all the people answered. I know you ppl spend your time. To be honest I was really surprised to see such detailed explanation. Please check my first comment of all replies to see this.

Comment: @knightrider No worries, I hope you enjoyed gnuplot. If your program is generating some output, of course you have a lot more freedom

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok to skip the connecting lines, then you can use a simplified version of @andyras second variant. Just define all functions to be `1/0` when outside a specified range:

```
set style data lines
unset key

f1(x) = (x > 0) && (x < 10) ? x : 1/0
f2(x) = (x > 10) && (x < 20) ? 3*x : 1/0
f3(x) = (x > 20) ? 10*x : 1/0

plot [0:25] f1(x), f2(x), f3(x)
```

Following yet another possibility. This assumes, that you can select a sampling high enough, so that the "jumps" which connect the functions are always greater than inside a function:

```
set style data lines
unset key

set xrange[0:25]
f1(x) = x
f2(x) = 3*x
f3(x) = 10*x
f(x) = ( (x>0)&&(x<10)?f1(x):(x<20)?f2(x):f3(x) )

set samples 1000

curr = 0
prev = 0
lim = 1
plot '+' using (prev = curr, curr=f($1), $1):(f($1)):(abs(curr-prev) < lim ? 0 : 1) lc var
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is what he *actually* needed

Comment: @christoph this one option. The other option I found till now which is more suited to me is to use `linesplot` so that I can see the marks over my original lines, so that I can differentiate the original lines.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the comments, I'm not sure if it is wise to add another solution... 
But for fun... another solution which differs from the given ones:

- does not require a datafile with 3 columns (@andyras)
- does not depend on `set samples`
- does not require to set a `dx` or `lim` which depend on the samples (@Bernhard, @Christoph)

The simple idea is to tell gnuplot in a variable `c1` in which piece of the function you currently are and change the color if you're going from one piece to the next piece. So, it's a kind of a compact mix of @andyras' and @Christoph's solution.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot transitions between piecewise function in different color
reset

set xrange[0:25]
f1(x) = x
f2(x) = 3*x
f3(x) = 10*x

x1 = 10   # break points for piecewise function
x2 = 20

f(x)  = x<x1 ? (c1=1,f1(x)) : x<x2 ? (c1=2,f2(x)) : (c1=3,f3(x))

plot c1=1 '+' u (c0=c1,$1):(f($1)):(c0==c1 ? 0x0000ff : 0xff0000) w l lc rgb var notitle
### end of script
```

Addition: In case you might want to let the red lines disappear...

- for gnuplot>=5.0.0 you can set a fully transparent color, e.g. `0xff123456`
- for gnuplot>=4.4.0 & <5.0.0 you could set it to white `0xffffff` (if this is your background)

**Result:**

Standard `set samples` is `100`. That's why the red lines are not fully vertical. You can get them "more vertical", e.g. if you `set samples 1000`.

[image]