# Trace a curve with two colors?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, curve

is there a way to have a curve with two colors, well i have many curves in my plot. But I like to add a specific characteristic, i want the curve 1 to be **simple line** in[a,b] interval, and **dotted line** in interval [b,c].

an example of my graph:

plot exp(-x**2 / 2), sin(x)

can we make sin(x) plotted in dotted line from[0,5]

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gnuplot change color of the connecting lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037858/gnuplot-change-color-of-the-connecting-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the line type on a certain interval with the `linetype` keyword to the plot command.  I don't think there is a way to make linetype a function of interval without doing it manually.  For example:

```
plot exp(-x**2/2), [0:5] sin(x) lt 1 lc rgb 'green', [5:] sin(x) lt 2 lc rgb 'green'
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thats would definitely be the best solution, but it works only with the development version, with 4.6.5 it doesn't.